# change url slug of encrypted cakephp script

Tags: url, cakephp, slug

I'm using a licensed cakephp script where appcontroller.php, bootstrap.php, and most of the core files are encrypted.

How do I change the url slug http://mydomain.com/property/cool-activity to http://mydomain.com/activity/cool-activity without affecting any other code?

There are many files and code that are named property or properties including a PropertiesController and PropertyUsersController.

The "cool-activity" slug was created by adding a new property listing "Cool Activity" and I know that to change the slug "cool-activity" can be done in the mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to routing and is a configuration issue.

First you have to identify the corresponding controller and action for the `/property/` part of your URL. Do this by searching the `routes.php` for statement like:

```
Router::connect('/property/*', array('controller' => 'XYZ', 'action' => 'XYZ'));
```

If you have found this statement change the `'/property/*'` to `'/activity/*'`.

I hope this solves your issue. If not a look in the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) might help!

Comment: Thanks! I see this would be the best way to do it. However, my App/Controller/AppController.php is encrypted, and I think there are set locks to prevent some changes. Is there a workaround to this?